# Draw Something on more than one device

Tags: draw-something

I have an iPad and iPhone, can I use the same account on both devices? If so, do I need to be careful and frequently sync the devices to the cloud?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can play on both devices. The game automatically syncs to the cloud, so you don't need to do anything special. Just log in on both devices and it will work.

Comment: How does this relate to cross-platform games?  i.e. one device running iOS, another running Android?

Comment: Worth mentioning: I was greeted with a message today that read, "It appears you are trying to play on multiple devices. Please limit play to a single device."

Comment: @Fluttershy I've seen that message too, but I've never actually witnessed any ill effects as a result. *shrug*